# What happens when link and monitor the same process in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

If process A link to B and A monitor B, when B dies, what happens to A? will A receive two messages? one is monitor 'Down' message and the other is exit message from B, if it is, what's the order abd what will A do?

Comment: It depends on whether process A is trapping exits or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When links and monitors are triggered they send out *signals* - you can read about this in more detail here: https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#signals

Looking at the BEAM emulator code, it turns out that the links are triggered before the monitors when a process dies - see erl_process.c: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/erl_process.c#L14149

I can't seem to find this fact documented anywhere, but I would guess it's to ensure that if process A doesn't trap exits, it gets killed immediately when the exit signal from process B arrives. If it got the monitor signal first, it might start acting on it but then get killed halfway through the action when the exit signal is received.